# Identify a condition among variables that satisfy an inequality

Tags: equation-solving, conditional, variable, constraint

I have a symbolic function that produces the output

```
a = (1 - e - mu/n) Log[(1 - e - mu/n)/(1 - mu/n)] + (e + mu/n) Log[((e + mu/n) n)/mu]
```

If I substitute `mu` in the above with `x-n e`, I get,

```
b = (1 - e - (-e n + x)/n) Log[(1 - e - (-e n + x)/n)/(1 - (-e n + x)/n)] + (e + (-e n + x)/n) 
    Log[(n (e + (-e n + x)/n))/(-e n + x)]
```

How do I get Mathematica to check whether `b>a` when `mu>x-n e`?

Other constraints on the variables are as follows

```
x-ne>0&&n>mu&&1-mu/n>e>0
```

EDIT

Heres a numerical analysis of the problem

```
Clear[x, n, \[Epsilon], \[Delta], \[Mu]];
n = 10^10; Manipulate[
 Show[ContourPlot[
   N[(1 - \[Epsilon] - (x - n \[Epsilon])/n) Log[(
        1 - \[Epsilon] - (x - n \[Epsilon])/n)/(
        1 - (x - n \[Epsilon])/n)] + (\[Epsilon] + (x - n \[Epsilon])/
         n) Log[(n (\[Epsilon] + (x - n \[Epsilon])/n))/(x - 
          n \[Epsilon])]] - 
    N[(1 - \[Epsilon] - \[Mu]/n) Log[(1 - \[Epsilon] - \[Mu]/n)/(
        1 - \[Mu]/n)] + (\[Epsilon] + \[Mu]/n) Log[(
        n (\[Epsilon] + \[Mu]/n))/\[Mu]]], {x, n \[Epsilon], 
    10^9}, {\[Mu], 0, 10^9}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   ColorFunction -> "StarryNightColors", 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True], 
  Plot[x - n \[Epsilon], {x, 0, 10^9}]], {\[Epsilon], 10.^-11., 10^-2,
   10.^-10.}]
```

[image]

x axis is the variable `x` and y axis is the variable `mu`. `n` is a fixed value (`10^10`) and `e` is manipulated. The blue diagonal line plots the value `x - n e`. The plot is positive for `mu` values above the line `x - n e`.